# What is MASK Marketing (Massive Array of Structured Keywords)?

Tags: sem

I recently had a client ask me about `MASK marketing for keyword searches`. Not familiar with the term, I did some research and found a [Fortune article](http://fortune.com/2015/06/29/turning-data-into-profits/) that said the following:

> Many companies miss out on sales because they limit themselves to using thousands of keywords in their search engine marketing (SEM). You’ll get the best results if you use a new automated technology called MASK, an acronym for massive array of structured keywords. It employs millions, rather than thousands, of keywords. The method was developed by Gauss & Neumann, an SEM research lab staffed by Ph.D.s. For one big airline client that used it, says CEO and co-founder Alberto Cabezas-Castellanos, “sales went up 53% in one year.”

The only [information I can find](http://gauss-neumann.com/en/mask/) is from the company that the Fortune article cites.

My questions:

1. What is this?
2. Is this just some proprietary software/system that is exclusive to this one company?

I am attempting to find out if this is something I need to learn about or ?

Comment: Sounds like a term for their custom software to me.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - That is what I am thinking but I wanted to check. You never know what cool new thing someone will come up with and share with the world. =>

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to get into trouble. I cannot help but to think of the trouble J.C. Penny got into a few years ago that got them delisted. This does not sound too far off from that.

Comment: @closetnoc - I remember reading about that. Interesting to consider it close to the same. For those that come across this post and do not know about the incident with them, [check out this article](http://searchengineland.com/new-york-times-exposes-j-c-penney-link-scheme-that-causes-plummeting-rankings-in-google-64529).

Comment: It seems like you and I are the only ones that remember ancient history... they were not the only company, but the biggest one that got caught or the biggest one outed by the NY Times.

Comment: To be fair, this seems more geared toward advertising. But it also sounds like an expensive route. If they have deep pockets, then perhaps.

Comment: @closetnoc - Did you see their pricing? When you click `Find out more about MASK` they have three options under SEM Investment... `< 500k or Less a Month`, `500k to 1M a Month`, `> 1M a Month`. Deep pockets indeed.

Comment: H0ly Cr@p Bat Man! Save your cash. I will do it for half!! ;-)

Comment: @closetnoc - You're hired! haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, they make each word on the web page, which is meaningful for the page's subject, to machine readable keyword, make it to structured data. Then they enrich each structurized keyword with its meanings, synonyms and translations. Then they exclude negative keywords, which could be similar to positive, but should never be associated with the page's subject. The goals are:

- to provide for any page the biggest possible structurized keywords set
- to make the meaning of the website machine readable
- to provide as more as possible machine readable connotations
  This all is done to make a page rank to as more as possible keywords.

[Read at thinkwithgoogle a case study](https://goo.gl/0L3LIq) about usage of mask by Iberia airlines